# Force loaded / displayed image to link to an html ( my post ) page in colorbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I'm using custom meta data to display images as a post in wordpress.  When I click the image on my main page it opens in colorbox and this is perfect.

WHAT IS HAPPENING : now, with the image loaded into the colorbox, when I click on the image it cycles through the images on my home page ( NOT what I would like ).

WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO HAPPEN : with the image loaded into the colorbox, when I click on it, it will act as a link and load the post ( associated with that image ) into the colorbox.

I'm not clear on how to do this.  The code I'm using to display the image meta data for the posts is:

```
        <?php

        // check for spine image
        $spine = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'spine image', $single = true);

        // check for spine class
        $spine_class = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'spine class', $single = true);

    ?>

    <div style=" #position: center; #left: 50%; height: 650px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">

        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <div class="entry">

                <?php

                    // If there is a spine image, display it as the post
                    if($spine !== '') { ?>

                    <p>
                        <a rel="bookmark" href="<?php echo $spine; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $spine; ?>" class="<?php if($spine_class !== '') { echo $spine_class; } else { echo "left"; } ?>"
                                height="400" onMouseOver='resizeImg(this, 150)' onMouseOut='resizeImg(this)'
                            />
                        </a>
                    </p>

                    <?php } // end if statement

                    // if there's not a spine image
                    else { echo ''; }
                ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

And the function I'm using for colorbox is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
    $("a[rel='bookmark']").colorbox({transition:"fade"});
});
</script>
```

So that the links with the attributes of 'bookmark' will open in the color box.  How now can I make it so that the image in the colorbox links to the associated web page ( or act as a link to any web page... one step at a time )?

I hope this makes sense and thank you for any help,
mlord

Answer (score 1):

My question seems overly complicated once I realized how to do this.

The end result is that I used the ".inline" HTML structured example from the website ( http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example4/index.html ).  I can put the image from the wordpress loop href'd to the permalink and call it inline for each image / post to be displayed in the colorbox.  Then I included the general colorbox class on that link which opens the post inside of the colorbox as well.  Awesome!

Keep care,
Matthew

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to your own question, mlord! I've up-voted you. :)